# Reusing an object after inserting it as a value into a collection

Tags: c#, reference

I experienced the following issue when playing with HashTable, but it is a general problem:

Say I have:

1. Some class (e.g., `Cat`), containing some member (e.g., public `Age` property).
2. A HashTable with some key (e.g., `string`) and a `List<T>` value (e.g., `List<Cat>`).

Is there a way to instantiate a single instance of a `List<Cat>` and reuse it so that it results in a desirable way:

```
Hashtable catDictionary = new Hashtable();    

Cat cat1 = new Cat() { Age = 10 };
Cat cat2 = new Cat() { Age = 12 };
List<Cat> catList = new List<Cat>();
catList.Add(cat1);
catList.Add(cat2);

catDictionary["oldCat"] = catList;

catList.Clear(); // This undesirably clears the list in HashTable["oldCat"]
Cat cat3 = new Cat() { Age = 2 };
catList.Add(cat3); // Now the list in HashTable["oldCat"] references a young cat!
catDictionary["youngCat"] = catList;
```

I mean, can the reference to `List<cat>` within `HashTable["oldCat"]` get its own copy of the inserted `List<Cat>`, so that it will be "detached" from the copy referenced inside `main`?

I guess I could ask the same about reusing the `Cat` object, but reusing the `List` feels more useful in a way.

Comment: Add cat3 to a new list, else it will be referenced same list

Comment: You have to use First(), Last(), or Take() to get individual items.  Or enumerate through list using Select/Where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list you will insert into the dictionary will have to be a new one, otherwise any changes you will make to the main list will affect the dictionary one (because they are basically the same instance with two refernces to it).
I also suggest you to use generic Dictionary instead of Hashtable
Try this using [LINQ ToList() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new copy of the list:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Cat>> catDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Cat>>();    

Cat cat1 = new Cat() { Age = 10 };
Cat cat2 = new Cat() { Age = 12 };
List<Cat> catList = new List<Cat>();
catList.Add(cat1);
catList.Add(cat2);

catDictionary["oldCat"] = catList.ToList();

catList.Clear(); 
Cat cat3 = new Cat() { Age = 2 };
catList.Add(cat3); 
catDictionary["youngCat"] = catList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a new list, else it will be the same list.

```
Hashtable catDictionary = new Hashtable();
Cat cat1 = new Cat() { Age = 10 };
Cat cat2 = new Cat() { Age = 12 };
List<Cat> catList = new List<Cat>();
catList.Add(cat1);
catList.Add(cat2);

catDictionary["oldCat"] = new List<Cat>(catList);

catList.Clear(); // This undesirably clears the list in HashTable["oldCat"]
Cat cat3 = new Cat() { Age = 2 };
catList.Add(cat3); // Now the list in HashTable["oldCat"] references a young cat!
catDictionary["youngCat"] = catList;
```